# wampserver icon showing in browser after uninstalling

Tags: browser, xampp, localhost, wamp, favicon

Why is it that after uninstalling WAMP and going to XAMPP for development, I am still getting the pink WAMPserver icon on my website tabs as the favicon? If anything my localhost site pages should be showing the orange and white XAMP icon in my browser right? Is there any way to fix this without having to manually change the icon on every single page I develop? I have no idea where my computer or localhost is getting this setting to use that pink icon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You dumped your cache?

Comment: that was it thank you! Can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks again!